# Ec2 Smtp Port connection refused issue not able to recieve emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, aws-security-group

When I try to do

telnet goodin.hk 25

It gives connection refused on EC2 instance this is the issue do anyone know how to resolve this

I have this port turned on in security groups configuration.

Comment: Inbound to EC2 needs the firewall opening and then an SMTP service running on the host.  Outbound from EC2 usually needs consent from EC2 staff since they have restrictions.  This information is over 2 years old knowledge maybe their policy is different now.  If you are seeing an immediate connection refused this usually means you are hitting the target system but it is not running the SMTP service.

Comment: when I try to send email to my server on EC2 it doesn't get to it 
I have postfix intsalled on it

Comment: A default install of postfix on Linux these days only binds to 127.0.0.1 and not a externally visible network address.  Use `netstat -an | grep :25` to confirm.  Check `/etc/postfix/main.cf` for `inet_interfaces = all` and edit, then restart postfix.  Use google search to help with more details on  reconfiguring postfix to be publically accessible (so you don't become a SPAM source).